# How to create a template for "could not convert string to float"?

Tags: python

Is there a way to test a CSV file for errors? For example, I have a CSV file downloaded from Kaggle. When I try to run it in Anaconda, it throws an error.

- a) How do you test files before you run them for string to float errors?
- b) Is there a way to set up a template to do this for all files moving forward?

Here is the text from notepad. I have converted all text to numbers and still throws an error.

My code:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# load the dataset
dataset = loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
```

**data.csv file**

```
15,1,14,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
34,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
52,5,16,4,1,37,37,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
46,3,21,4,0,0,0,1,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
42,3,23,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
51,3,17,6,1,34,3,0,0,1,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1
26,1,26,3,0,0,0,1,2,1,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
45,1,20,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
44,3,15,0,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
44,3,26,4,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
27,1,17,3,0,0,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
45,4,14,6,0,0,0,1,10,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
44,2,25,2,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
43,2,18,5,0,0,0,0,0,1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
40,3,18,2,0,0,0,1,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: A template? _My code:_ Please provide the code that actually leads to the error message (a [mcve]), as well as all the output you receive. _run it in Anaconda_ ?

Comment: Though you could set up your own special "lint" script or shared function to test your csv input for errors, IMHO you don't gain much from that because all of the requirements for the csv's contents are already coded into your main script, albeit indirectly. I suppose a separate lint script could catch these problems faster maybe, and there is probably value in spitting out a more readable error message, but as I said IMO in many circumstances it wouldn't gain you much and in some ways it's a duplication of code. That's my opinion anyway. I'm sure there are exceptions.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `statistics`, `artificial-intelligence`, or `anaconda` - please do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Not sure anyone actually read the question? If you copied the ^ code into Python and ran it you would get an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿15.00". My question is, what kind of code could I write to check the CSV file before running in a Deep Learning algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like certain CSV files from Kaggle & others have encoding issues.

Instead of opening the file with the default encoding (which is 'utf-8'), use 'utf-8-sig'.

```
dataset = loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Once I create some code to scan for this PRIOR to running in a deep learning algo, I will post it as follow on.